# How bad is coulombs Force

Tags: weapon-mass-destruction

Electrostatic force is number 2 in an ordered list of discovered fundamental forces by strength. So to test out its strength some highly advanced aliens think it would be great to check whether they can blow up planets with it. They have a device than simply converts matter into a sea of electrons with 97% efficiency(For example if use use this device on 100 atoms of helium it generates ~97*8 = 776  electrons in their place while using the mass of helium to power itself) . These kindhearted aliens then turn to our planet (a.k.a the earth) to test their device. They think that using their device to turn 50% of earth's inner core to electrons would be fun (Assume this device replaced all of the targets atoms/molecules at once).

But how much damage could this awesome weapon cause to a planet if used without caring for the energy requirements?

Also If the above experiment is done is there any way that life on the planet might survive?

Comment: You mean, apart from the fact that losing 50% of the inner core would be quite catastrophic by itself?

Comment: I think you're talking about the teenage kids of some advanced aliens, rather than a decision taken after adult consideration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Your question has already been answered

http://what-if.xkcd.com/140/

> Proton Earth, Electron Moon
>
> What if the Earth were made entirely of protons, and the Moon were made entirely of electrons?
>
> —Noah Williams

Answer:

> This is, by far, the most destructive What-If scenario to date.

...and if you know your *xkcd: What If*'s, then that tells you how utterly bad this scenario is.

The TL;DR version:

> In the case of an electron Moon, the energy from all those electrons pushing on each other is so large that the gravitational pull wins, and our singularity would form a normal black hole. At least, "normal" in some sense; it would be a black hole as massive as the observable universe.
>
> Would this black hole cause the universe to collapse? Hard to say. The answer depends on what the deal with dark energy is, and nobody knows what the deal with dark energy is.
>
> But for now, at least, nearby galaxies would be safe. Since the gravitational influence of the black hole can only expand outward at the speed of light, much of the universe around us would remain blissfully unaware of our ridiculous electron experiment.

Comment: you copied your cheatcode wrong - *If you put 1e52 electrons together—to build a Moon—they push each other apart really hard. In fact, they push each other apart so hard, each electron would be shoved away with an unbelievable amount of energy.* Nothing changes with OP's 1/1000 conversion rate

Comment: having read the xkcd explanation, i would like to highlight one thing:
this will make a naked singularity (black hole without event horizon) and depending on how dark energy really works, this could destroy the UNIVERSE
so please do not try this at home